# Sorting data.frame in r

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I want to sort `R` `data.frame` when it has only one column. How can I get the output as `data.frame` (Output should be a data.frame with rownmaes)? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
set.seed(12345)
df <- data.frame(X=rnorm(n=10, mean=0, sd=1))
rownames(df) <- LETTERS[1:10]
df

           X
A  0.5855288
B  0.7094660
C -0.1093033
D -0.4534972
E  0.6058875
F -1.8179560
G  0.6300986
H -0.2761841
I -0.2841597
J -0.9193220

df[order(df$X), ]

[1] -1.8179560 -0.9193220 -0.4534972 -0.2841597 -0.2761841 -0.1093033
 [7]  0.5855288  0.6058875  0.6300986  0.7094660
```

Comment: `df[order(df$X),, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg for your help. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Now you can delete if you want

Comment: Linked to the previous question (where the correct answer has been given). You don't need to take any action, the mods will take care off it.